# Headphones don't work on Dell Studio XPS 16 with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, dell, headphones, audio-jack

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Studio XPS 16 and the headphone jack isn't working. The internal speakers work fine. I have tried a lot of suggestions from different posts, but none of them work.

Comment: Could you give us more details about what you tried? Otherwise we won't have a clue what to suggest.

Comment: Did you try running `amixer` from the terminal and unmuting everything?

Comment: Like I posted a few minutes ago: install pavucontrol and see if you can use the settings in there to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the mute button and then push it again. This happens to me too. That should work ,I think.